# Tomcat error with Hibernate 3.5.1

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa-2.0

I just upgraded to hibernate 3.5.1 and I get an error now saying:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval () Z.
```

This only happens with Tomcat not with Jetty.

I've checked and I don't have any conflict and this method definitely exists. I have hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar on the class path, and don't have any conflicting classes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the maven tomcat deploy process was copying in the old EJB JAR.
When I did it manually it works fine.